# filter in nested ngFor always undefined on source parameter Angular 8 Pipe

Tags: angular, filter

I am using Angular 8.

I have  a filter that keeps me giving the value undefined for it's source parameter , and I dont understand why since I can always vizualise the element that the filter is considering undefined.
 I have the following filter:

```
filter(source :string, target :string, method:Method) : boolean {
    console.log("filter");
    console.log(source, target, method);
    switch(method) {

      case "includes" : return source.includes(target)
      case "equal"  : return source === target
      case "not-equal" : return source !== target
    }

  }

}

type Method ="includes" | "equal" | "not-equal"
```

And the following html that I can see all elements just fine if I don't apply the filter at all :

```
  <div *ngFor="let cat of filteredArray | filter : 'cat.category' : selectedCategory : 'equal'" >
          <mat-tab *ngFor="let errlist of cat.errors" label="{{errlist.letter}}">
              <div class="tab-content ">
                  <ul class="errorUL ">
                    <li *ngFor="let item of errlist.errorList  " >
                         {{item.id}} - {{item.description}}
                     </li>
                    </ul>
              </div>
```

so what I missing here? is this not how the filter works?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had written it wrong, with cat.category instead of just category

this is the correct way:

```
 <div *ngFor="let cat  of filteredArray  | filter : 'category' : selectedCategory : 'equal'">
```

Answer (score 1):

The declaration of your filter looks very confusing. I suppose you are using Angular with typescript and not AngularJs, so you have to use Pipes instead of filters. [Here is the official guide upon this](https://angular.io/guide/pipes#custom-pipes).

If you somehow still use AngularJS and filters, your filter declaration and usage is wrong in many ways. Please take a look at [this tutorial](https://ultimatecourses.com/blog/everything-about-custom-filters-in-angular-js). In short:

- You don't use filter like `filter : 'category'`. As I can remember, you use the keyword you declared this filter to. Unfortunately I don't see any declaration like `app.filter('makeUppercase', function () {` you can find in the tutorial.
- You don't have types in AngularJS method properties.
- You have to tell AngularJS the name you want to reach this filter.
- I don't see from where the `source` and `selectedCategory` properties should get their values?

Comment: I am using angular 8, with a custom pipe yes

Answer (score 1):

within your pipe, It appears to me that you're handling an array of objects as **string**, then returning a single string, not a filtered array of objects.

anyway, here's an example of a filter pipe I'm using

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
    name: 'filter',
    pure: false
})
export class FilterPipe implements PipeTransform {

    transform(items: any, property: any, term: any): any {
        if (!term) {
            return items;
        }

        const result = items.filter(function (item) {

            if (item[property] === null) {
                return items;
            }
            if (item[property].toString().toLowerCase().includes(term.toLowerCase())) {
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        });
        if (result.length === 0) {
            return [-1];
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```